# How to change spring batch Transaction Isolation level

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I  am trying to launch a job with JobLauncher  with below  code

```
    @RestController
    public class SystemController
    {
        static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SystemController.class);

        JobExecution jobExecution;  
        @Autowired
        JobLauncher jobLauncher;

        @Autowired
        Job job;



        @RequestMapping(value ="/abccontext" ,method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        @ResponseBody
        public String handleResquest(@RequestBody final Data resData)
                throws Exception
        {

                JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", dateFormat.format(date)).addLong("time", Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();

    jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);
            }
}
```

i have configured job with same id in batchjob.xml

## batchjob.xml

```
<job id="job">
// steps

</job>
```

some time I  have  received  below mention error msg

> PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into
>   BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values
>   (?, ?, ?,  ?)]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
>   ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't
>   serialize access for this transaction

Database: oracle 11g,

SO i want to change the isolation level to READ_COMMITTED.

any help will be appreciable. thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set it up at the job-repository level

```
<batch:job-repository 
    id="jobRepository"
    data-source="your-dataSource" 
    transaction-manager="your-transactionManager"
    isolation-level-for-create="READ_COMMITTED" />
```